# PHP in JS and separation of the two

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So I am working on a big project that was started quit a few years ago and in that time as it tends to happen many programmers worked on it, so the code atm is quit a mess and it is slow. One of the practices that really bothers me tho is that HTML, PHP and JS are all in the same file and that is the norm here. It is also one of the reasons for pages slow load speed that and also sometimes horrible SQL syntax.

But since I have been given freedom about how I do certain things I want to ask a question.

If I put the whole JS in separate file it will not work by just copy pasting it due to a bad practice that looks like this

```
 var var= <?php echo $var; ?>;
```

this works if everything is in the same file, but if I separate the files this of course fails. Now I would like to know how it would be easiest way to request data from PHP with JS as well as if I can call PHP functions from JS in any other way then through AJAX? Or should I just write a lot of AJAX requests?

Comment: For this type of scripts, you must have to go for Ajax... and you can't use keyword `var` as variable name...

Comment: "HTML, PHP and JS are all in the same file". Hard to separate the HTML and PHP usually, since PHP is used to generate the HTML (and sometimes parts of the JS, too), unless you do a complete re-write using something with a templating or view engine, like an MVC framework.

Comment: To answer more directly, you can't call PHP functions from JS while JS is executing on the browser, since the PHP runs on the server and has already finished executing. You can either embed values statically (like your example above), or fetch them from the server at runtime using ajax. If you're worried about performance, replacing that embedded value with an ajax call adds another HTTP request and isn't likely to improve performance, plus you have to derive that value again from wherever it came from, during the second request (since the context of the main request is long gone).

Comment: The act of combining PHP, HTML and JS into one page is not, in itself, a direct cause of poor performance. In fact it's likely to produce faster load times than having separate HTML and JS files, for instance, since a separate JS file requires a separate HTTP request to download it. If those JS files can be cached, however, you might get a gain. There's a lot more to this topic than simply separation of code types (that might be nice for maintainability but it's not a direct indicator of speed). You mention horrible SQL too - that might be a better place to look for inefficiencies.

Comment: Yash, I just name var as an example, but thanks anyway

ADyson, we are caching JS, but since it is not in static files it doesn't really do much. And I am improving SQL where and when I can, but other obligations for maintaining and improving the project don't give me much time for that. I am just trying to figure out best practices before I put quit a bit of time into this.

Comment: Obviously I don't know a lot about the project, but make a list of all the tasks you'll need to do, and the time you think it'll take, and then consider whether a complete re-write might actually be quicker and easier, and allow future enhancements to be made more easily, as well as future-proofing with newer technology and techniques. Sometimes it can be worth it, depending how much the existing codebase has decayed. You can put lipstick on a pig, but it's still the same old pig underneath. Anyway I hope my comments are useful in helping you to clarify your thoughts to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I have also worked on similar kinda projects. My solution for these kinda problems were, using global JS variables.

Load the global variables in `<head></head>` tag.

```
<head>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var var1 = <?php echo $var1; ?>;
        var var2 = <?php echo $var2; ?>;
    </script>
</head>
```

Now load your script just befor `</body>` or anywhere after the global variables are loaded from PHP, all the global variables can be accessed by your custom script.

```
<body>
.
.
<script src="YOUR_CUSTOM_JS_PATH"></script> 
/* Now in your custom JS file you can easily access variables `var1`, `var2`.*/
</body>
```